# How to deserialize array of arrays with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have JSON like this:

```
[[1,"A"],[2,"B"]]
```

I'm trying to deserialize it with:

```
public class A {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
  }

String jstring = "[[1,\"a\"], [2, \"b\"]]";

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<A>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<A> enums = gson.fromJson(jstring, collectionType);
}
```

And getting error

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

As i understand gson expect

```
{"id":1, "name":"b"} instead of [1,"b"]
```

So how can I deserialize this JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an array of array of mixed types, aka a list of list of mixed types, use:

```java
... = new TypeToken<List<List<Object>>>() {}.getType();
```

```java
List<List<Object>> enums = ...
```

Gson will not map an array to a POJO. For what you want, the JSON should have been:

```json
[{"id":1, "name":"a"}, {"id":2, "name":"b"}]
```

As is, converting the `List<List<Object>>` into a `List<A>` is up to you.